# Asp.net MVC DataContext issues when crawled with Xenu with 50 parallel threads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, iis-7

Having some very strange issues and don't know what these are about.

I have an asp.net mvc2 site. I am using Linq to SQL classes (`.dbml`) for data access. Database is in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Everything is fine and my site is working perfectly. Issues starts when I crawl my site using Xenu and I starts getting whole bunch of different issues. Following are examples of some of them.

> *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
>
>   Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.*
>
> *Member AutoSync failure. For members to be Auto-Synced after insert, the type must either have an auto-generated identity, or a key that is not modified by the database after insert.*
>
> *New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor.*
>
> *Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

What is confusing me more is I stop the Xenu and visit the same pages after 2 minutes and they starts working fine.

I have published the site on IIS7 on site on window server 2008.

Just looking for a hint so that I can troubleshoot, currently have no idea where to start.

Information on Xenu's Link Sleuth: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu%27s_Link_Sleuth

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just killing your server.  50 high speed parallel threads on your local LAN?  Dial it back a bit.  I think these errors are due to overloading.  Yes, there is probably a flaw in your implementation, or things you could do to make it better.  Database and IIS on same machine?  Is this the load you are expecting?  You are probably just fine.

Comment: Thanks for coming onto it, Here's the details you asked.

1.) No site is not published on local line, it's on real dedicated server with very good configuration.

2.) Even I set the threads to low number (I tried 10), I still gets the most of these problems. But don't face them when actually browse the site without Xenu running.

3.) Yes database and IIS are on same machine

4.) As I pointed above I tried with 10 which is reasonably acceptable on a real site.